# How to reference a 'global' variable?

Tags: pug

I'm using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) client-side. How can I reference a global JavaScript object within my template?

For example, I have the following in my Jade template:

```
span.row-count (#{window.App.numberFormat(tbl.rows)})
```

`window` is supposed to refer the global `window` object defined on every page, but when my template is compiled, I can see that it puts this:

```
function(locals) {
    jade.debug = [ {
        lineno: 1,
        filename: "views\\tables.jade"
    } ];
    try {
        var buf = [], locals_ = locals || {}, tables = locals_.tables, window = locals_.window;
        ...
```

Notice how it redefines `window`, thinking it's a local (passed in) variable, when it isn't. How do I prevent it from being passed into the locals table?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141223/accessing-window-object-in-remote-nodejs-app

Comment: @MikeCauser: Not the tiniest bit related.

Comment: This, OTOH is related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17537049/65387

Comment: I just noticed in [the options](http://jade-lang.com/api/) you can pass in "a list of globals (as string names) to make accessible in templates"

Answer (score 1):

You can [copy the variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17537049/65387) into the local context (a bit of a hack):

```
for (var key in window) {
    if (!context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        context[key] = window[key];
    }
}
```

Or you should be able to utilize the [`globals` option](http://jade-lang.com/api/):

> Add a list of globals (as string names) to make accessible in templates